# Visual Studio Code - associate html formatter with razor file type without changing highlighting

Tags: html, razor, visual-studio-code, formatting, syntax-highlighting

I would like to format razor files using the standard html formatter, however I do not want to change the highlighting. 
Using the `files.associations` like so:

```
files.associations {
    "*.cshtml": "html"
}
```

also changes the highlighting. Is there a way to only register an existing formatter with a file type without also registering a different highlighter?